# how to repeat a map in a list many time?

Tags: scala

if I have a map defined as

```
val lookup=Map[String,Double]("abc"->1,"c"->2)
```

Then I need to create a list whose element is lookup, and then let it repeat 10,000 times.
I need something like

```
List(lookup).repeat(10000)
```

But I can't find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val lookup=Map[String,Double]("abc"->1,"c"->2) 
lookup: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(abc -> 1.0, c -> 2.0)

scala> List.fill(5)(lookup)
res0: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]] = List(Map(abc -> 1.0, c -> 2.0), Map(abc -> 1.0, c -> 2.0), Map(abc -> 1.0, c -> 2.0), Map(abc -> 1.0, c -> 2.0), Map(abc -> 1.0, c -> 2.0))
```